# Converting string to ObjectId is failing in mongoose 4.6.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to convert a string to ObjectId using

```
var body={};
var objId="57b40595866fdab90268321e";
body.id=mongoose.Types.ObjectId(objId);

myModel.collection.insert(body,function(err,data){
//causing err;
});
```

the above code is working fine when mongoose 4.4.16 is used, but if i update my mongoose to latest version(4.6.0) then problem occurs.

**Err**

```
  object [
  {
    "_bsontype":"ObjectID",
    "id:{"0":87,"1":180,"2":5,"3":235,"4":134,"5":111,"6":218,"7":185,"8":2,"9":104,"10":50,"11":111}
 }
] 
is not a valid ObjectId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to insert new document is-

```
var newDocument = new myModel({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("57b40595866fdab90268321e")
});

newDocument.save();
```

In you case-
It stops working because the differences between versions of mongoose and mongo native drivers.

although, you are able to perform this by the example above, or, if you still want to use `insert`, you can use the `myModel.insertMany` (by passing object instead of array)

look here
 http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to spike it, but if I remember correctly `id` is a simple string and `_id` is the ObjectId, i.e. either

```
body.id="57b40595866fdab90268321e"
```

or

```
body._id=mongoose.Types.ObjectId("57b40595866fdab90268321e");
```

That said, does it have to be *that* specific id? If not, you can use `new myModel()` and an id will be automatically created.